# oral instructions vs verbal instructions

Tags: phrase-usage, difference

I was given an assignment to correct any mistakes in some given sentences. I saw no real mistake in the sentence below:

> Preparing to parachute from the airplane, Cameron received verbal instructions instead of written ones.

But the answer says that it is *oral* instructions, not *verbal* instructions. However, I think people also say "verbal instructions" and cannot find the difference between these two phrases (even though I've googled). How are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While many native English speakers use these interchangeably, "verbal" could be considered less precise.  From wiktionary:

> [oral](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oral#English): 1. Relating to the mouth. 2. Spoken rather than written.
>
> [verbal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbal#English): 1. Of or relating to words. ... 4. Expressly spoken rather than written. ...

Since definition 1 of "verbal" is "of or relating to words," [some people argue](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/oral-or-verbal) that all instructions that involve words could be called "verbal instructions."  I don't agree with them.  However, given that this argument exists about possible ambiguity, the clearest solution is to use "oral instructions," which has no possible ambiguity.

Comment: In the given sentence *verbal* can scarcely be misconstrued as meaning "written" seeing that the two are explicitly contrasted, and therefore there's no need to replace it with *oral*. The [ODE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verbal) gives this example sentence "Patients who understand and can apply written or verbal information and instructions have better outcomes." for the "Spoken rather than written; oral." sense of *verbal*.

Comment: I agree. I think the people who reject this usage are being obtuse. But they still exist in [significant numbers](https://www.google.com/search?q=oral+vs+verbal).